# Observable merge runs with TypeError: cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I am trying to implement a sort DataTable in an angular application, and [the example](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples) I am implementing runs with the following error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
    at TableDataSource.webpackJsonp.332.TableDataSource.connect (data-table.component.ts:83)
```

The method that causes the error is the Observable.merge():

```
connect(): Observable<UserData[]> {
    const displayDataChanges = [
      this._exampleDatabase.dataChange, //BehaviorSubbject
      this._sort.sortChange, //EventEmitter
    ];

    return Observable.merge(...displayDataChanges).map(() => {
      return this.getSortedData();
    });
}
```

Do you have any idea about the cause of this error? I googled for an explanation of the message that I am getting but with no success

Comment: Well, probably an item in `displayDataChanges` is undefined :)

Comment: @martin I checked the items of `displayDataChanges` and they contain both well defined objects

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just found the cause of the problem: I had to import the merge!

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/merge';
```

I paid attention to this by reading the answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36585491/typescript-rxjs-observable-array-concat
.

Comment: Additionally I had to change `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';` to  `import { Observable } from 'rxjs';`